# Wait for Cmd process to end -java

Tags: java, maven, process

Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c cd \""+path+"\" & start cmd.exe /k \"mvn clean install\" & wait");

int i = p.waitFor();

print(p);

Answer (score 1):

Okay just solved it..

Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c cd \""+path+"\" & start /wait cmd.exe /k \"mvn clean install\"");

worked